# PHP controlling where a table is placed on a web page

Tags: php, html, css

I'm new to PHP and I'm working on a very simple SELECT query pulling information from a MySQL database. I have an `echo` statement that prints out that my connection to the database was successful which is the very first line on the webpage. After "Connected Successfully" is display the SELECT statement pulls the query information into a table.
Right now everything is pulling and displaying correctly but there is a large gap between my `echo` connection statement and the actual table results. I've tried to directly align my table to 'TOP' but that is still producing the large gap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
#trip th {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

#trip {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 75%;
}

#trip td, #trip th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#trip tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#trip tr: hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
</style>

<body>
<?php
    require "Login.php";
?>

<?php

//Create Connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $password, $dbName);

//Check connection
if ($conn === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not Connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connected successfully";

//SQL SELECT query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Trip";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table id='trip' align='top'>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>TID </th>";
                echo "<th>NAME </th>";
                echo "<th>DATE </th>";
                echo "<th>COST </th><br>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['TID'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['NAME'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['DATE'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['COST'] . " </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        //Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        echo "No records matching your query were found";
    }
}
else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

//Close connection
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like the table to display right underneath my "Connected Successfully" message but something seems to be putting the table further down the page.

*Edit* Fixed the '\' that was added when I tried to paste into Stackoverflow. Not sure why that was added. It's not in my actual PHP file.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: Why do you have backslashes here: `echo "<td>" . $row\['TID'\] . " </td>";`? That's not valid PHP syntax.

Comment: @Barmar Not sure why that '\' was added. That's not in my PHP file. That was added when I tried to paste into Stackoverflow and use the code formatting.

Comment: Very strange. I've seen lots of indentation glitches when pasting into SO, but never seen extra backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `<br>` you have at the end of this line:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['COST'] . " </td><br>";
```

Since `<br>` isn't allowed inside `<tr>` elements, the browser is rendering them before the table. So the number of blank lines before the table is the same as the number of table rows.

Get rid of that, it serves no purpose.

```css
#trip th {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

#trip {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 75%;
}

#trip td,
#trip th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#trip tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#trip tr: hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div>Connected successfully</div>
<table id='trip' align='top'>
  <tr>
    <th>TID </th>
    <th>NAME </th>
    <th>DATE </th>
    <th>COST </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TID</td>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>DATE</td>
    <td>COST</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TID</td>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>DATE</td>
    <td>COST</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TID</td>
    <td>NAME</td>
    <td>DATE</td>
    <td>COST</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```